# Using Postgres SQL, what is the fastest transaction to emulate an UPSERT for a single row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge, upsert

This question is about a single row, not a set. I'm just curious what is faster using the latest and greatest version of Pg (9.0) and why:

> A conditional UPDATE or INSERT on the basis of a SELECT on the PKEYs
>
> An attempt to INSERT, catch an exception on fail and falling back to an UPDATE
>
> An attempt to UPDATE, catching an exception on fail and falling back to an INSERT

I think because this would depend on the dataset lets assume three scenarios:

- 50% of the rows are present, 50% aren't present
- 100% of the rows are present
- 100% of the rows aren't present

Presence means the PKEYs are satisfied and the row should be updated. Any links to research on this would be great.

Comment: MERGE is the ANSI-2003 syntax: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SQL_MERGE

Comment: MERGE isn't in Postgresql yet.

Comment: RhodiumToad adds that option 1 has an implicit race condition, and there is no solution to this that doesn't involve exception handling.

Comment: Actually they all have race conditions.  If you take any one of those methods, and run it one line at a time in two different windows you can wind up with errors in your upserts.

Comment: this first one, "A conditional UPDATE or INSERT on the basis of a SELECT on the PKEYs", is an **invalid way to do an upsert**. @ScottMarlowe: the last two are fine if done within a transaction (with some extra logic involving a while loop to avoid deadlocks).

Answer (score 5):

The first scenario will never be faster than the other two, because the SELECT that you issue first is unnecessary additional work and is done implicitely by UPDATE (and possibly INSERT) as well.

Even with a 50% / 50% percent distribution I'd think that using UPDATE/INSERT will slightly be faster as the error handling (catching the exception) takes considerably more time than an UPDATE that does not update anything.

So I'd go for the UPDATE/INSERT pattern unless you know that really a **lot** (e.g. > 70%) of rows won't be there.

But only a good performance test in your environment can tell that.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of response I was expecting, I'm going to let it sit for a day before I accept it.

Comment: *I'd try the insert first only in cases where >90% of the time the row would not already be present.* - RhodiumToad #postgresql

Comment: To be safe you will probably end up writing UPDATE/INSERT and then catch errors on the INSERT by doing the UPDATE again, i.e. combine the two approaches. That should properly cope two parallel tasks targetting the same data. Presumably you need to create a savepoint to effectively catch the INSERT exception too?

Comment: ah, reading the docs again, looks like plpgsql automatically handles creating the savepoint as part of the begin..exception..end construct

Answer (score 0):

In postgres 9.5, it will be possible to perform an actual upsert:

http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=168d5805e4c08bed7b95d351bf097cff7c07dd65

```
INSERT [...] ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET [...] WHERE [...]
```